# Getting vertex weights with the vertex proximity modifier

Tags: scripting, modifiers

I am trying to use the Vertex Proximity Modifier to update vertex weights and hoping to be able to read the same with Python.

I have a plane and a vertex group called "all" (which includes all the vertices and default weight 0.0) and the proximity object is set to a sphere. The modifier behaves as expected. But when I try the following code:

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.active_object # select the plane

for i in range(0, 24): # I know there are 25 vertices
    print (obj.vertex_groups['all'].weight(i))
```

I get 0.0 printed out for each vertex. Can I get the individual weight of each vertex with the modifier in action but **not** applied? (If I apply the modifier, then I get the intended results.)

Answer (score 1):

## Use [bpy.types.Object.to_mesh](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68_release/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.to_mesh):

> ```
> to_mesh(scene, apply_modifiers, settings, calc_tessface=True, calc_undeformed=False)
> ```
>
> Create a Mesh datablock with modifiers applied

This leaves your object unchanged and gives access to the modified vertex groups, e.g.

```
import bpy

mesh = bpy.context.object.to_mesh(bpy.context.scene, True, "PREVIEW")
for vertex in mesh.vertices:
    for group in vertex.groups:
        print(vertex, group, group.weight)
```

Comment: Works great! I was using bmesh - so I had to write it back to a mesh before this produced the expected results. Sorry I had missed giving the information about the bmesh earlier. Thanks a ton!